# is there a way to edit configuration.nix like visudo with the sudoers

Tags: nix

introduction:

In this thread (https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/47201), in order to fix my problem, it is said to add this 2 lines.

```
services.xserver.enable = true
virtualisation.docker.enable = true;
```

to

> /etc/nixos/configuration.nix

---

Now my question:

I used to work with the sudoers file. And in this link it said to NEVER edit it with a text editor.  Because an improper syntax can leave you with a broken system.

Can an improper syntax have big repercussions on nix?
Is there a way to avoid it like visudo.

Comment: A broken `sudoers` file doesn't break your system. It just breaks your ability to use `sudo`, which (unless you have the root password and can use `su`) prevents you from editing the `sudoers` file to fix it. A broken `configuration.nix` just breaks your ability to build a new system from that file, without breaking your *current* system.

Answer (score 1):

Editing your nixos configuration is much less risky than editing your sudoers file. So you don't have to hesitate to edit it with a normal text editor or worry about having syntax errors. After using Nixos for a few years now the only thing that went 'wrong' for me is messing up a config and my build process attempted to build packages that would have taken very long (but it  was easy to cancel this).

If there are any syntax errors it'll just return an error. And in the worst case where you mess things up you should be able to just rollback to previous config with `nixos-rebuild switch --rollback`. Or boot back into the previous working generation.